# Not able to sign in to gitlab after upgrade

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I upgraded gitlal omnibus from gitlab-ce-12.0.2-ce.0.el7.x86_64  to gitlab-ce-12.0.3-ce.0.el7.x86_64.

Post which when I launch the URL http://10.28.19.103:8080 it redirects to http://10.28.19.103:8080/users/sign_in.

In that I only see a sign in btn. Upon clicking nothing happens. I have no space to enter to enter username and password.

The logs are as below:

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started GET "/" for 10.28.208.19 at 2019-07-05 01:02:15 +0800
Processing by RootController#index as HTML
Redirected to http://10.28.19.103:8080/users/sign_in
**Filter chain halted as :redirect_unlogged_user rendered or redirected**
Completed 302 Found in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.28.208.19 at 2019-07-05 01:02:16 +0800
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log <==
{"method":"GET","path":"/","format":"html","controller":"RootController","action":"index","status":302,"duration":17.38,"view":0.0,"db":0.54,"location":"http://10.28.19.103:8080/users/sign_in","time":"2019-07-04T17:02:15.975Z","params":[],"remote_ip":"10.28.208.19","user_id":null,"username":null,"ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36","queue_duration":3.56,"correlation_id":"fqMPRtqjdO3"}

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 32.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
Started GET "/uploads/-/system/appearance/header_logo/1/ytlc.png" for 10.28.208.19 at 2019-07-05 01:02:16 +0800
Processing by UploadsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"model"=>"appearance", "mounted_as"=>"header_logo", "id"=>"1", "filename"=>"ytlc.png"}
Sent file /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/uploads/-/system/appearance/header_logo/1/ytlc.png (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log <==
{"method":"GET","path":"/users/sign_in","format":"html","controller":"SessionsController","action":"new","status":200,"duration":54.1,"view":32.47,"db":2.17,"time":"2019-07-04T17:02:16.020Z","params":[],"remote_ip":"10.28.208.19","user_id":null,"username":null,"ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36","queue_duration":5.03,"correlation_id":"T9vwNeRZZZ6"}
{"method":"GET","path":"/uploads/-/system/appearance/header_logo/1/ytlc.png","format":"html","controller":"UploadsController","action":"show","status":200,"duration":17.42,"view":0.0,"db":1.47,"time":"2019-07-04T17:02:16.768Z","params":[{"key":"model","value":"appearance"},{"key":"mounted_as","value":"header_logo"},{"key":"id","value":"1"},{"key":"filename","value":"ytlc.png"}],"remote_ip":"10.28.208.19","user_id":null,"username":null,"ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36","queue_duration":4.3,"correlation_id":"Wsuv3JkKIj2"}

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started GET "/-/metrics" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-07-05 01:02:18 +0800
Processing by MetricsController#index as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log <==
{"method":"GET","path":"/-/metrics","format":"html","controller":"MetricsController","action":"index","status":200,"duration":6.82,"view":0.67,"db":0.0,"time":"2019-07-04T17:02:18.715Z","params":[],"remote_ip":null,"user_id":null,"username":null,"ua":null,"queue_duration":null,"correlation_id":"2e2fdaf8-4f81-4075-b9b5-1c34055bafba"}

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sidekiq_exporter.log <==
[2019-07-05 01:02:18] 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jul/2019:01:02:18 +08] "GET /metrics HTTP/1.1" 200 3501 "-" "Prometheus/2.8.1"
```

I took a backup of the current repositories, installed a new GIT on temp VM. Imported the above repository.

But again I faced the same problem.

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

You should not be accessing GitLab via port 8080. That's Unicorn, and it shouldn't be listening externally by default. You should access GitLab via port 80 or 443 through Nginx.

If you've set Unicorn to listen on port 8080 on something other than localhost, I suggest setting that back to default and accessing via the configured external URL (which should be port 80 or 443).